# Swift programmatically set segues

Tags: swift, parse-platform, segue

I have a piece of parse code that checks to see if a user is logged in:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("myname", password:"mypass") {
  (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if user != nil {
    // Do stuff after successful login.
  } else {
    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
  }
}
```

After the successful login I want to send the user to a new segue. I can't do this in the storyboard because I only want the segue to occur if the conditions are met. Is there anyway to create a segue programmatically?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
```

You dont need to "create" a segue programmatically, just connect your ViewControllers and create a Segue. With performSegueWithIdentifier you can call your segue manually if needed.

Comment: Gotcha... So I would click and drag from the view controller 1 to vc 2?