# Selecting the object at index in a MapView in SWIFT

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am trying to present another view controller once the right callout button is pressed but it must go to the correct indexPath, similar to how this happens in a table view. this is where I am up to:

I have created a custom annotation like so:

```
class annotationCustom: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title : NSString!
    var subtitle : NSString!
    var isUserAnnotation : Bool
    var dataImage = [NSData]()

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: NSString!, subtitle: NSString!){

        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.isUserAnnotation = false
    }
}
```

and then set the `viewForAnnotation` like so:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        var dqPin = "pin"

        var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(dqPin) as? MKPinAnnotationView

                view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: dqPin)
                view!.canShowCallout = true

                    var arrowBut = UIImage(named: "arrow")
                    var arrowButton = UIButton()
                    arrowButton.setImage(arrowBut, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    arrowButton.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    arrowButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
                    view!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = arrowButton
                   }
             return view
             }
```

Now I know I have to use the function:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
            func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {

        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let userProfileVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("usersProfileVC") as UsersProfilesViewController

                userProfileVC.profileName = annotationCustom.title // error: 'annotationCustom.Type' does not have a member named 'title'

        performSegueWithIdentifier("goToUserFromMap", sender: self)
    }

}
```

}

Can somebody fill in the gaps or help me out please.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is not clear?  If you're wondering how you know which annotation the method is being called, it's `view.annotation` (a reference to the `annotationCustom` object that you added).

Comment: What i'm not sure how to do is once the right callout accessory is tapped, how do i segue to the next view controller from the indexPath of that particular annotation. I don't know how to write/do it?

Comment: Don't think of or use "indexPath" with annotations.  They don't have a specific order to the map view like rows do to a table view.  The calloutAccessoryControlTapped method gives a direct reference to the annotation in question that you access using `view.annotation`.  **Regarding how to do the segue:** see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805954/mkannotationview-push-to-view-controller-when-detaildesclosure-button-is-clicked.  It's in Objective-C but it should not be difficult to convert to Swift.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536080/swift-programmatically-set-segues.

Comment: I understand that bit, but how do i write it e.g. for a table view you would write something like this:  
       `var secondVC : UsersProfilesViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UsersProfilesViewController  secondScene.profileName = self.profile.names[indexPath.row]`  using the `indexPath` to reference to the selected row. I don't know how to reference to the selected annotation to be able to pass information across.

Comment: Add whatever data is needed per annotation (eg. profileName:String!) to your custom annotation class (annotationCustom).  When _creating_ the annotations, set the profileName (copy it from the profile.names[x]).  Then in the delegate method, the view.annotation object will have the data right with it (you won't need to refer back to the source data).

Comment: I have edited my code slightly although I am getting an error, how do I call the rightCalOutView?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
```

it should be:

```
if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
```

`view` is the internal, private name of the parameter and `annotationView` is the external name visible to the caller.

However, in this case, you don't really need to check `control` in the first place since your callouts have only a single control (`rightCalloutAccessoryView`).  They don't have a `leftCalloutAccessoryView` so there's only one control the user could tap.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {

    println("disclosure pressed on: \(view.annotation.title)")

}
```

---

By the way, is the code shown in `viewForAnnotation` the actual code?  Because it looks like the result of the `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` is ignored and there is a mysterious extra closing `}` before the `return view`.

---

Here:

```
userProfileVC.profileName = annotationCustom.title
```

`annotationCustom` is the name of your *class* -- not the *instance* of it (also, convention is to start class names with a capital letter).  `view.annotation` is the instance here.  Cast it as `annotationCustom` to access any custom properties (though `title` isn't custom):

```
if let ac = view.annotation as? annotationCustom {
    userProfileVC.profileName = ac.title
}
```

Comment: No it wasn't the full code as i made it smaller so it was easier to understand, I have edited my code again as the function is running now I just don't know how to pass over information in the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`. I can't work it out...?